# Alternative for _.invert() using underscore library

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I need to change the existing map swapping keys into values and values into keys. As there is duplicate values in my map for the keys I cannot use _.invert() of underscore library.

```
function map() {
        return {
             'eatables': {
                 apple: 'fruits',
                 orange: 'fruits',
                 guava: 'fruits',
                 brinjal: 'vegetables',
                 beans: 'vegetables',
                 rose: 'flowers',
             }
        }
    }

    var reverseMap = _.invert(map()['eatables']); 
// invert function works for distinct values.
    console.log (reverseMap); 
// which is giving Object {fruits: "guava", vegetables: "brinjal",flowers:"rose"}
```

But i am expecting an output as

```
Object {fruits: ["apple","orange","guava"], vegetables: ["brinjal","beans"], flowers:"rose"}
```

I tried as below, i just stuck how to find whether map value is distinct or multiple?

```
   var newObj = invert(map()['eatables']);
_.each(newObj, function(key) {
    if (Array.isArray(key)) {
        _.each( key, function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        });
    } else {
        console.log("else:"+key);
    }
});

function invert(srcObj) {
    var newObj = {};
    _.groupBy(srcObj, function(value, key ) {
        if (!newObj[value]) newObj[value] = []; //Here every thing is array, can i make it string for values which are unique.
        newObj[value].push(key);
    });
    return newObj;
}
```

Let me any alternative  using underscore library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function. This function uses [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to generate  an array containing the keys of the object passed in input. Then, it accesses the values of the original object and use them as key in the new object. When two values map to the same key, it pushes them into an array.

```
   function invert(obj) {
    var result = {};
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (var i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (result[obj[keys[i]]] instanceof Array) {
            result[obj[keys[i]]].push(keys[i])
        } else if (result[obj[keys[i]]]) {
            var temp = result[obj[keys[i]]];
            result[obj[keys[i]]] = [temp, keys[i]];
        } else {
            result[obj[keys[i]]]=keys[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6f2ptxgg/1/

Comment: Thanks @Giuseppe, when i ran the code i got output as  Object {fruits: Array[3], vegetables: Array[2], flowers: Array[1]}. But i am expecting the flowers value as string not as an array as it is having only one value.

Comment: so if there is one element you want just that element not an array

Comment: Yes, Otherwise while parsing the newly created object we should parse through array to get only one element in the array.

Comment: @NaveenkumarChinnakalappa fixed. Try it.

Comment: Thanks @Giuseppe, Your code works fine. But i am looking code with underscore library, where this can be done even easier.

Comment: I thought you couldn't use `underscore`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83844/discussion-between-naveenkumar-chinnakalappa-and-giuseppe-pes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the underscore [each](http://underscorejs.org/#each) to iterate through your data and push the result in an array. It should give you your expected output.

```
function customInvert(data) {
    var result = {};
    _.each(data, function (value, key) {
        if (_.isUndefined(result[value])) {
            result[value] = key;
        } else if(_.isString(result[value])) {
           result[value] = [result[value], key];
        } else {
           result[value].push(key)
        }            
    });
    return result;
}

customInvert({
   apple: 'fruits',
   orange: 'fruits',
   guava: 'fruits',
   brinjal: 'vegetables',
   beans: 'vegetables',
   rose: 'flowers',
 })
```